# how to restrict access to admin folder except logged user

Tags: php, admin, restrict

I have folder /admin/index.php
how to restrict access to that folder except logged user.
I try to restrict access with .htaccess but it restrict access at all

Comment: Well, what have you tried?

Comment: when i logging to mysql i check if the user type is admin. IF is admin   loading admin/index.php but every visitor can acces admin page. I try with .htaccess - deny from all but deny and logged user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your /admin/index.php are you checking these things:

1. Is the user logged in? - If not, redirect them to the login page.
2. Is the logged in user an Admin? - If not, redirect them to another page.

Seems like the logical way to tackle this.